# Specify Which Area is Date to Sort

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, tablesorter

I want to have a `TD` with more information than just the date in it, but this messes up the comparison. Is there a way to specificy a class to give dates for the comparison to look for? In this example, if I try to sort on the first 2 dates, it works fine but the 3rd date will not work because of the "Event Information" string. Can I seperate the two without creating new tabledata?

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
  $("table").tablesorter({
    widthFixed : true,
    widgets: ["filter"],
    widgetOptions : {
      filter_formatter : {
        0 : function($cell, indx){
          return $.tablesorter.filterFormatter.uiDateCompare( $cell, indx, {
            dateFormat : 'M dd, yy',
            changeMonth : true,
            changeYear : true,
            compare : '='
          });
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<table class="tablesorter">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-placeholder="Sort By Date">Date (one input; greater than)</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Jun 26, 2013</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Aug 21, 2013</td></tr>
    <tr><td><span class="compareDate">Oct 13, 2013</span><div class="info">Event Information</div></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Jul 6, 2013</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Dec 10, 2012</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

An older version of the plugin I found you could use something similar to the code below, but I'm not sure how to implement that in the current version of the plugin.

```
{filterContainer: $("#container"), filterColumns: [3], filterCaseSensitive: false, filterCellProcessor: function(node) { return $(node).find("span.datefilter").text();}, filterFunction: filterByDate}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use a custom textExtraction property during the sorter's initialization to isolate the date for those cells that have additional markup:

http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-option-text-extraction.html

Something like this should do the trick:

```
textExtraction: function(node) { 
  return (node.childNodes[0].childNodes.length > 0) ? 
    node.childNodes[0].innerText : 
    node.innerText ;
}
```

Here's a fiddle that demonstrates using it with varying levels of internal cell markup:

http://jsfiddle.net/NetsydeMiro/hkLdh/

It includes handling the two date formats in your question (vanilla, and span with a following div), but may require some changes to the node parsing if you anticipate even more types of markup (such as the dropdowns and text inputs you mentioned).  I think you just need to account for any expected markup formats and/or fallback to a sensible default.

Comment: Wouldn't this apply to All sort functions and not just a specific one  though? If I have multiple sort functions (dropdowns, text inputs, etc.) then I'm not sure if this would work, but i'll keep looking into it thanks!

Comment: In that case I guess you'd have to implement a conditional switch in the formatter function that handles the different data and markup permutations, depending on their types.  It might get a bit hairy... let me know if you find a cleaner way, and good luck!

Comment: Right, even with the extracted data though i'm not entirely sure what to do with it or where to set it so that it works well with the datepicker / filter_formatter. I'll keep this updated with what I find but even looking into the plugin core code i'm not sure.

Comment: I've added a jsFiddle example that looks like it should work.